# Form hangs while encrypting text in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a function in vb.net which encrypts text with some password like this:

```
Public Class PROT
Shared Function EncryptWithPassword(Target As String, Password As String) As String

'Target is the given text
'Password is the password

Dim datas as string =""

'store the encrypted text and with password in datas and return it

Return datas
End Function
End Class
```

I use this function like this in my Form:

```
Private Sub encryptbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles encryptbtn.Click
   Dim texttoencrypt As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim passwordtotext As String = passwordbox.Text
    Dim enc As String = PROT.EncryptWithPassword(texttoencrypt, passwordtotext)
    IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Ubaada\Documents\SAFE.txt", enc)
End Sub
```

When the length of text in Textbox1 is smaller than 5000 then the code hangs the form for only 2 seconds. But when I tried it with a length of 100000 it hanged the form and won't be responsive anymore. Shouldn't it be responsive within 40 secs (since 100000 is 20 times bigger than 5000).

---

My Question is that how can I manipulate the code so that it will not hang the form and work with string of length 100000 or greater. I've heard about threading but i think i cannot use it like this:

```
Dim enc as string=Thread.Start(PROT.EncryptWithPassword(texttoencrypt, passwordtotext))
```

---

Comment: Threads, TPL, async - use whichever is available in your framework version. Don't expect execution time to scale linearly, it may heavily depend on the algorithm.

Comment: The most pressing problem is that your encryption is woefully inefficient. An encryption should be much, *much* faster. Furthermore, encrypting passwords is most likely wrong anyway. Passwords should be stored hashed, not encrypted in almost all instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing the code in the same thread as the UI, and thus it will hang when the task is taking some time. You can solve this indeed by using threading.

I would use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) in this case. It is very simple to set up. You don't have to worry too much about how to set up the threading. You just need to implement the `DoWork` and if you want, the `RunWorkerCompleted` event(s).

You can assign a value to the `Result` property of the `EventArgs` of the `DoWork` event. You should be able to access this value in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event in the `EventArgs`, `Result` property.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx):

> If your operation produces a result, you can assign the result to the [`DoWorkEventArgs.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.result.aspx) property. This will be available to the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event handler in the [`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result.aspx) property.

Comment: But i can't use background worker to produce a value after finishing its work as I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes you can, assign a value to the `Result` property of the `EventArgs` of the `DoWork` event. You should be able to access this value in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event in the `EventArgs`. (As you could read in the documentation.)